# Getting UnsupportedClassVersionError when invoking remote application

Tags: java, unsupported-class-version

I'm developing a consumer for my application which run on Java 6 which is calling a remote provider application which runs on Java 7. This throws the following Exception:
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/company/package/EPCSecurityServices_kkggls_EPCSecurityServicesRIntf : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
Please advise if it is possible to overcome this problem without upgrading the client application to Java 7.

Comment: You'll need to compile that class targeting Java 6...

Comment: @JonSkeet - you mean the class on the remote application? The problem is that I'm not the owner of that application and they may be servicing other clients which use Java 7.

Comment: I mean the class that's causing the problem - the one listed in your question. Note that a Java 7 JVM can run Java 6 code - just not vice versa.